# Плавающее меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день! Я новичок в программировании.
Прошу помочь сделать плавающее меню (http://echo.md).
Хочу, чтобы при скроллинге страницы вниз шапка (где меню и лого) уменьшалась вдвое и крепилась к верху броузера.

Все перепробовал, ничего не выходит.
Знаю, что CSS грязный/неверный, я пытался хоть что-то прицепить. :)

Благодарю за ваше время!

**HTML:**

```
<div><script src="/js/floatingmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="header-one" class="default">
        <div id="brand">
            <div id="logo">Logo</div>
            <div id="logo2">Logo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $menu = $("#header-one");

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 && $menu.hasClass("default")) {
            $menu.removeClass("default").addClass("fixed");
            $('#logo').fadeOut(0, function () {
                $('#logo2').fadeIn();
            });

        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 50 && $menu.hasClass("fixed")) {
            $menu.removeClass("fixed").addClass("default");
            $('#logo2').fadeOut(0, function () {
                $('#logo').fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
 #brand {
     /* блок, который служит оберткой для логотипа и контактов  */
     float:left;
     width:30%; }
 #logo {
     font-size:28px;
     color:#fff; }
 #logo2 {
     display:none;
     /* блок контактов изначально скрыт и появится только при прокрутке */
     font-size:12px;
     color:#fff; }
 #header-one {
     width: 920px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 50px;
     background: #69c; }
 #header-one ul {
     float:right;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     width:70%; }
 #header-one li {
     display: inline;
     list-style:none;
     margin: 5px 10px; }
 #header-one li a {
     padding:5px 10px;
     color:#fff;
     text-decoration: none; }
 #header-one li a:hover {
     background: #36c;
     color: #ff0; }
 #header-one.default {
     width:920px; }
 #header-one.fixed {
     position:fixed;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     width:100%; } .clear {
     clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень много таких вопросов уже было)

Для фиксирования при скролле можно вот так:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $block = $('#block'); // ID шапки

    if($(window).scrollTop() > $block.offset().top) { // Тут идея в том, что блок привязывается к верху, как только "прилипает" к верху окна браузера. Замените $block.offset().top на любое значение и получится, что когда вы проскроллили на большее кол-во пиксейлей, чем указали, добавиться класс к шапке.
        $block.addClass('fixed'); // Добавляем класс fixed. В стилях указываем для него position:fixed, height и прочее, чтобы сделать шапку фиксированной.
    } else {
        $block.removeClass('fixed'); // удаляем класс
    }
});
```

Разумеется, в CSS нужно написать стили для класса fixed, чтобы зафиксировать нужный вам блок.

**UPD.** [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/3jvuwctf/1/)

Comment: Спасибо за столь скорые ответы. Попробовал оба варианта. У меня не выходит...

Вот так пытаюсь связать HTML и JS: 

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/floatingmenu.js"></script>

Это верно?

Он вообще ничего не привязывает к топу, папку и файл правильно указал.
Уже столько времени убил на это, хотя пишут что просто... А я вот не догоняю. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment:     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/floatingmenu.js"></script>

Выучите HTML и CSS для начала)) Пару минут, откомментирую свой код

Comment: И... Добавил простой пример

Comment: Пример очень помог! Спасибо большое!
Вот только у вас шапка уменьшается, а у меня нет... (jQuery 2.1.3 стоит).
Код как две капли воды*. Не могу понять в чем дело ))

Comment: Всё поправил. :)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не уменьшается шапка, как в вашем примере?

Comment: @saha9  Откройте DevTools (правой кнопкой мыши в браузере -> проверить элемент) и посмотрите добавляется ли класс fixed (или какой вы указали) к шапке. Если нет, то там же открывайте консоль и смотрите что пишет

Comment: @inferusvv Класс <...> применялся не к тому элементу :)
Посмотрите пожалуйста http://echo.md/ .
1. Очень резко шапка "урезается", не как в вашем примере. Как?
2. Элемент шапки, а именно лого и меню "не на своем месте" получаются. Для вас это раз плюнуть, а у меня уже голова не варит, и тэги снятся :)

Спасибо огромное за помощь и ваше время.

Comment: Плавность сделана с помощью transition. Чтобы меню и лого не улетали, пишите другие стили для шапки с классом collapsed. Уменьшайте padding'и, margin'ы и т.п.

Comment: А если это на пример меню слева, а как мне его перед футером остановить?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4kwkjmd0/

Comment: Спасибо за столь скорые ответы. Попробовал оба варианта. У меня не выходит...

Вот так пытаюсь связать HTML и JS: 

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/floatingmenu.js"></script>

Это верно?

Он вообще ничего не привязывает к топу, папку и файл правильно указал.
Уже столько времени убил на это, хотя пишут что просто... А я вот не догоняю. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: может, вы не подключили библиотеку http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Подключение_jQuery

Comment: Добавил, 2.1.3...

Comment: ссылка на страницу есть?

Comment: http://echo.md/

Сейчас смотрю... шапка есть только в Мозилле)))

Comment: Все поправил. :)